# Анимация по очереди, а не одновременно

Tags: jquery, анимация

При добавлении двух блоков с анимацией они анимируются одновременно, а надо, чтобы сначала раскрылся один, затем по завершении второй.

```js
$service = '<div style="display:none;">Сервисный текст</div>';
$desc = '<div style="display:none;">Описание</div>';
function add() {
 $("#feed").append($service, $desc);
 $("#feed > div:nth-last-child(n+1)").slideDown('fast');
}
```

```css
#feed > div{
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid silver;
 background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="position:fixed;top:0;" onclick="add();">Добавить текст</button>
<div id="feed"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$service = '<div style="display:none;">Сервисный текст</div>';
$desc = '<div style="display:none;">Описание</div>';

function add() {
  
  $("#feed").append($service);
  $("#feed > div:last-child").slideDown('fast', () => {
    $("#feed").append($desc);
    $("#feed > div:last-child").slideDown('slow')
  });
}
```

```css
#feed>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="position:fixed;top:0;" onclick="add();">Добавить текст</button>
<div id="feed"></div>
```

Comment: Ваш код как-то странно добавляет блоки с "описанием" в геометрической прогрессии...

Comment: Начиная со второго нажатия кнопки код перестает выводить блоки по очереди, снова начинает выводить их одновременно и начинает наращивать количество блоков $desc в геометрической прогрессии.

Comment: @Kodek подправил

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас постараюсь разобраться что там написано и что изменилось =)

Comment: @Kodek удачи..! )